# Gmail not detecting PTR record from vultr server

Tags: smtp, gmail, dig, ptr-record, vultr

I have an SMTP server running on a vultr VM. I've set up the rDNS to point to my mail domain name `mail.idimitrov.dev`. The DNS setup points to that machine on ipv4 and ipv6 for `mail.idimitrov.dev` and it points to github pages on `idimitrov.dev`.

When I send emails to gmail only, it tells me that there are no PTR records.

```
                   |    host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [2a00:1450:4013:c07::1b]
                   |    SMTP error from remote mail server after pipelined end of data:
                   |    550-5.7.25 [2001:19f0:6c01:2f25:399c:6832:fa7c:c123] The IP address sending this
                   |    550-5.7.25 message does not have a PTR record setup, or the corresponding
                   |    550-5.7.25 forward DNS entry does not point to the sending IP. As a policy,
                   |    550-5.7.25 Gmail does not accept messages from IPs with missing PTR records.
                   |    550-5.7.25 Please visit
                   |    550-5.7.25  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#ip-practices for more
                   |    550 5.7.25 information. fl6-20020a1709072a8600b008b466a03af6si17950149ejc.3 - gsmtp
```

This is not the case for other mail providers.

I changed the rDNS settings to point to `idimitrov.dev` and tested again. Same result.

Here is the output of the `dig` command:

```
   ~ ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── at   08:55:53
❯ dig -x 209.250.239.243

; <<>> DiG 9.18.12 <<>> -x 209.250.239.243
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 64879
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
; COOKIE: 96ded523f01fcbcb0100000063f70e07b977d3b949d3c8d8 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;243.239.250.209.in-addr.arpa.  IN      PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
243.239.250.209.in-addr.arpa. 3321 IN   PTR     idimitrov.dev.

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.1#53(192.168.0.1) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Thu Feb 23 08:56:07 EET 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 112


   ~ ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── at   08:56:07
❯ dig -x 2001:19f0:6c01:2f25:5400:04ff:fe48:12ba

; <<>> DiG 9.18.12 <<>> -x 2001:19f0:6c01:2f25:5400:04ff:fe48:12ba
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 32491
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
; COOKIE: 82062aa836133bb70100000063f70e0a54a88c9478150aaa (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;a.b.2.1.8.4.e.f.f.f.4.0.0.0.4.5.5.2.f.2.1.0.c.6.0.f.9.1.1.0.0.2.ip6.arpa. IN PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
a.b.2.1.8.4.e.f.f.f.4.0.0.0.4.5.5.2.f.2.1.0.c.6.0.f.9.1.1.0.0.2.ip6.arpa. 3445 IN PTR idimitrov.dev.

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.1#53(192.168.0.1) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Thu Feb 23 08:56:10 EET 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 156
```

It shows that I have rDNS setup for both ipv4 and ipv6.

Why does google say otherwise?

Comment: Try `dig -x 2001:19f0:6c01:2f25:399c:6832:fa7c:c123 @1.1.1.1 `. I don't see any reverse DNS defined.

Comment: @vidarlo Google thinks I'm sending mail from a different IP apparently. My vultr dashboard shows the IP I used in the dig command, but the gmail log shows a different IPv6 IP. I'll have to open a ticket with them maybe. brb